# PostgreSQL notifications and WebSockets with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, websocket

Is there any Ruby/Rails library for sending PostgreSQL [asynchronous notifications](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-notify.html) via WebSockets?

I need to notify a browser client for updates in a specific database table. I know this can be done with pub/sub APIs, but I'm looking for a Postgres only solution.

I've found a [Python tutorial](http://initd.org/psycopg/articles/2010/12/01/postgresql-notifications-psycopg2-eventlet/) for this, but couldn't find one for Ruby. I need to implement this for production use, so a production-ready library and tutorial would be the best.

Comment: I wrote a Rails3-Plugin for exactly this scenario. Sadly it is closed source (it was paid work), but you can implement it on your own very easily. There is a `EventMachine` plugin for websockets and you can use Model.execute() to listen/notify. Only thing you have to bare in mind is that MRI is not multithreaded (look for GIL), so I used jruby instead of MRI for the websockets server.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know directly about any that does work with websockets, but queue_classic gem uses listen/notify in postgres for a message queueing. It's a good way to start looking how it can be done.